# Add test description in report

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there a way to add custom text in testcafe reports?
I would like to add a short description in the reports, so when somebody else checks it to be able to understand what the test does (especially when the test is passed, only the test name appears in the report and I cannot write too much text in the name of the test,it makes no sense). The problem is that I have different functions checking some menus and only 1 test scenario. I would like to add a text to know which functions were called.

console.log('custom text') will write the text only in the console
this.write('custom text') used inside a async function gives an error.

class goThroughAllMenus{

```
constructor(){

}
async f_CheckHomeMenus() {
//Description: This function is going through all submenus under Home page 
//              and checks that the pages are 'up and running'.   
    this.write(`Running test for Home menu`) 
    await t
    //Hjem
        .click(StartPage.HomeMenus.menuHome)
        .expect(StartPage.StartPage.StartSubMenu.exists).ok()
        
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in capability to pass custom data to the reporter. You can ping the already existing [issue in the TestCafe repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3584). However, if you just want to send common information about the whole test block, you can use [`meta`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402734/reference/test-api/test/meta) and [create a custom reporter](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403436/guides/intermediate-guides/metadata-and-filtering#include-metadata-in-run-reports) to show this information.

```js
//reporter.js
export default function () {
    return {
        async reportTaskStart (startTime, userAgents, testCount) {
        },

        async reportFixtureStart (name, path, meta) {
        },

        async reportTestStart (name, meta) {
        },

        async reportTestDone (name, testRunInfo, meta) {
            this.write(meta );
        },

        async reportTaskDone (endTime, passed, warnings, result) {
        }
    };
}
```

Also, you can create a fork of [any existing reporter](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402825/guides/intermediate-guides/reporters) and enhance one.